# My idea is ignored when I say it, but listened to when someone repeats it

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word or phrase to describe the situation when one person makes a comment or suggestion in a meeting and is ignored, but a few minutes later someone else makes essentially the same comment or suggestion and is listened to?

Comment: X's suggestion/comment is _rebuffed_, but Y's is accepted. Will that do?

Comment: This question is not at all the like the linked one.

Comment: 'It's the way you tell them.'

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the circumstances, *hepeating* might work:

> Every professional woman knows what it feels like to share an idea in
> a meeting and have it fall flat, only to hear that same idea repeated
> by a male colleague and have everyone applaud it.
>  <sub>Source:
> [How to combat ‘hepeating’ at work, according to a Harvard
> professor](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/10/11/how-to-combat-hepeating-at-work-according-to-a-harvard-professor.html)</sub>

Or *shepeating*, maybe.

Comment: Which reminds me- we should get lamb chops from a Costco.